# Can't setVisible true

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to set visible label with text. But GUI won't update it. Could you take a look at code and advice me?
I have few controller class, below I presented two of them. Action Main Screen is responsible for detection of clicks and Admin Log Panel should check if data are correct and update view.

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Model model = new Model();
                    MainScreen window = new MainScreen(model);
                    ActionMainScreen actionMainScreen = new ActionMainScreen(
                            model, window);
                    OpenClose openClose = new OpenClose();

                    actionMainScreen.connectToServer();
                    window.getFrame().setVisible(true); // GUI
                    actionMainScreen.contol(); // GUI controllers

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Controller (Action Main Screen):

```
public class ActionMainScreen {

    private MainScreen viewMain;
    private OpenClose openClose = new OpenClose();
    private ConnectionNetwork connectionNetwork = new ConnectionNetwork();
    private UpdateData updateData = new UpdateData();
    private Model model = new Model();
    private AdminLogPanel admPanel = new AdminLogPanel();

    public ActionMainScreen(Model model, MainScreen window) {
        this.viewMain = window;
    }

    public void connectToServer() {

        try {
            connectionNetwork.connectToServer();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.net.ConnectException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ConnectException");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void contol() {

        openClose.checkByTheFirstTime();
        updateData.changeText();

        viewMain.getBtnLogIn().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            String login;
            String password;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                login = viewMain.getTextFieldLogin().getText();
                password = new String(viewMain.getPasswordField().getPassword());
                admPanel.checkIfAdmin(login, password);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller (Admin Log Panel):

```
public class AdminLogPanel {

    Model model = new Model();
    MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen(model);

    public void checkIfAdmin(String login, String password) {

        if (ModelAdmin.getLogin().equals(login)
                && ModelAdmin.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("HURA!");
            mainScreen.getLblLoginOrPassword().setVisible(true);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OK");



        } else {


            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()); // true
                    mainScreen.getLblLoginOrPassword().setText("abc"); // correct text in console
                    System.out.println(mainScreen.getLblLoginOrPassword().getText());
                    mainScreen.getLblLoginOrPassword().setVisible(true); // nothing happened 


            mainScreen.getLblLoginOrPassword().repaint();
                mainScreen.getPanel_1().repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

View:

```
public class MainScreen {

    public MainScreen(Model model) {
        initialize();
    }

    private JButton btnLogIn;
    private JLabel lblLoginOrPassword;
    public JLabel getLblLoginOrPassword() {
        return lblLoginOrPassword;
    }

    public void setLblLoginOrPassword(JLabel lblLoginOrPassword) {
        this.lblLoginOrPassword = lblLoginOrPassword;
    }

    public JButton getBtnLogIn() {
        return btnLogIn;
    }

(....)
lblLoginOrPassword = new JLabel("Login or Password is incorrect!");

        lblLoginOrPassword.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 17));
        lblLoginOrPassword.setVisible(false);

}
```

Comment: The code you show here is missing all the important parts while listing tons of unimportant ones. What about `MainScreen.getFrame()`. Why are you not extending from JFrame etc?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

You're settings your window's visibility to true, but you're not setting the JLabel's visibility to true, also you could try calling pack(). Another useful tip would be to make sure your component is using a Layout, maybe something like CardLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I couldn't test your code. It is too large. But can you put the following code snippet, after your update code and see?

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(component);
```

Here "component" is the top level under the frame.